# C# : Currency Rendering Solution

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

i have to find a solution for this task :

"Supermarkets are increasingly equipped with automatic cash registers. Most of these funds only accept payment by credit card, although a significant proportion of consumers still pay cash (with banknotes and coins).

One of the problems encountered with the cash payment is the rendering of money: how to make a given sum optimally, ie with the minimum number of coins and notes? This is a problem for every one of us every day, let alone the automatic cash registers.

In this exercise, i m asked to try to find an optimal solution to make change in a specific case: when an automatic cash register contains only 2 € coins, 5 € and 10 € banknotes.

To simplify the problem, we will consider that all these coins and bills are available in unlimited quantities.

Here are some examples of currency:
[image]

The return of money is expressed by a Currency object. This item has 3 properties: piece2, billet5 and billet10 which respectively store the number of coins of 2 €, 5 € tickets and 10 € tickets.

For example, if we take example 2 of the table (6 €), we should get a Money object with:

- Piece2 worth 3 (3 pieces of 2 €)
- Ticket5 is worth 0 (no ticket of 5 €)
- Ticket10 is worth 0 (no ticket of 10 €)

**Task :** Implement the **MonnaieOptimale(int s)** method that returns a Currency object containing the coins and notes whose sum is **s**. If it is impossible to return the currency (as in example 1), return null.

To get it best the solution will always have to make change when possible and with the minimum number of coins and tickets."

Data: **s** is always a strictly positive integer (long) less than or equal to 9223372036854775807

the general structure of the solution is the following:[image]

**Suggestions ??**

Comment: You can solve it with simple mathematical ad-hoc algorithm since you know nominales in advance. Just solve it "on paper" and you will understand how to solve it on in C#. P.S. If nominales are not known in advance, then the problem can be solved with dynamic programming, but it takes `O(s)` time which is inadequate in your case.

Comment: Hint: it is **never** optimal to use coins of nominale 2 or of nominale 5 when you need to make it up to 10, and therefore to 10*N for every N.

Comment: Uni assignment?

Comment: "Implement the MonnaieOptimale(int s) method that returns a Currency object containing the coins and notes whose sum is s" seem to be solid suggestion already present in the question.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, please don't post images of code, post it as text. Also, can you improve the wording of the question itself? Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, simple greedy approach (always get the largest i.e.10) is not working here, as the system is not canonical, consider `s = 11`, you will get "Impossible" if you use coin 10, but it is possible with { 5, 2, 2, 2 }.

I have a slightly different idea here, using the parity of odd /even numbers:

1. If `s` is even, do the greedy approach but never uses coin 5
2. If `s` is odd, keep using coin 5 until `s` becomes even, then do step 1.

---

For eg: `s` = 18, solution = { 10, 2, 2, 2, 2 }. `s` = 23, solution = { 5, 10, 2, 2, 2, 2 }

Why it works, is because one can notice, for coin system { 2, 10 }, you can make any even `s` using greedy approach (it is canonical to even domain).

Plus the fact that for any odd number minus another odd number will make a even number, so for odd `s` we can use one coin 5 to make `s` even to reduce the problem.

From this logic, I think at most one 5 coin would be used for any `s`, and only when `s = 1 or 3` the answer is "Impossible"

Answer (score 0):

i solve it mannually like this:

```
public static Monnaie MonnaieOptimale(long s)
        {
            if (s<10)
            {
                if (s%2 =0) {Monnaie.billet10 = 0 ; Monnaie.billet5 = 0 ; Monnaie.piece2 = s/2 }
                else if (s == 5)  {Monnaie.billet10 = 0 ; Monnaie.billet5 = 1 ; Monnaie.piece2=0 }
                else if (s == 7)  {Monnaie.billet10 = 0 ; Monnaie.billet5 = 1 ; Monnaie.piece2=1  }
                else Monnaie.billet10 = 0 ; Monnaie.billet5 = 1 ; Monnaie.piece2= 2
            }

            else
            {
                if (s%2 =0) 
                {
                    Monnaie.billet10 = Math.Floor(s/10);
                    if ((Monnaie.billet10 * 10) != s) {Monnaie.billet5 = 0 ; Monnaie.piece2= (s%10)/2 }
                }
                else
                {
                    private lastDigit = s%10;
                    if (lastDigit ==1){Monnaie.billet10 = ((s/10)-1) ; Monnaie.billet5 = 0 ; Monnaie.piece2=3 }
                    else if (lastDigit ==3){Monnaie.billet10 = ((s/10)-1) ; Monnaie.billet5 = 0 ; Monnaie.piece2=4 }
                    else if (lastDigit ==5){Monnaie.billet10 = (s/10) ; Monnaie.billet5 = 1 ; Monnaie.piece2=0 }
                    else if (lastDigit ==7){Monnaie.billet10 = (s/10) ; Monnaie.billet5 = 1 ; Monnaie.piece2=1}
                    else {Monnaie.billet10 = (s/10) ; Monnaie.billet5 = 1 ; Monnaie.piece2=2}
                }

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;    
public class Program {    
public static void Main() {    
int re10 = 0, re5 = 0, re2 = 0, s = 197;     
while (s / 2 != 0) {          
    while (s / 5 != 0) {    
        while (s / 10 != 0) {    
             if (s % 10 % 5 == 0) {    
                  re10 = s / 10;    
                  s = s % 10;    
                     }   
              else {    
              if (s / 10 > 1) {    
               re10 = s / 10 - 1;    
               s = s % 10 + 10;    
              }    
              break;    
             }    
           }    
        if (s % 5 % 2 == 0) {    
             re5 = s / 5;    
             s = s % 5;    
            } else    
        if (s / 5 > 1) {    
         re5 = s / 5 - 1;    
         s = s % 5 + 5;    
        }    
        break;    
       }    
  re2 = s / 2;    
   s = s % 2;    
  }    
if(re5==3){re10+=1;re5-=2;}
 Console.WriteLine("billet 10 :" + re10);    
 Console.WriteLine("billet 5 :" + re5);    
 Console.WriteLine("billet 2 :" + re2);    
 Console.WriteLine("Total : "re2 * 2 + re10 * 10 + re5 * 5);     
 }    
}    

billet 10 :18
billet 5 :3
billet 2 :1
Total :  197
```